# "The domain example.com is no longer parked by GoDaddy." error message trying to host a Heroku App

Tags: https, godaddy

I have a Heroku App, a Godaddy domain (which I have added in my heroku app domains) and I need to use a free ssl provided by Cloudflare.

I am struggling to find out the best workaround for this. I could set it up by changing the nameservers in godaddy pointing cloudflare's but I got an error stating that the certificate is not secure.

Now, I have this error when accessing my .com domain. "The domain example.com is no longer parked by GoDaddy."

Comment: Are you getting that error in browser?

Comment: [CloudFlare has a guide for using their service with Heroku](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-CloudFlare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS), have you followed these steps? GoDaddy isn't really relevant here as they are just the Registrar and you will be moving DNS away from GoDaddy to CloudFlare.